# How to enable GraphQL Playgorund on a Production environment in .Net Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, graphql

I'm creating a sample project in .Net Core 3.1 with a GraphQL API that I'm going to use in a live demo session and I would like to be able to use the Playground in a Production environment.

I've searched the docs on how to do it but found nothing.

How can I achieve so?

Note that I'm running my API on a Docker container, my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env

WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./

WORKDIR /src/GraphQL.Sample.Api
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

COPY --from=build-env /src/GraphQL.Sample.Api/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GraphQL.Sample.Api.dll"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your startup.cs file.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...

        // use graphql-playground at default url /ui/playground
        app.UseGraphQLPlayground();
    }
```

Make sure you have the app.UseGraphQLPlayground() line and that it is not inside an if.

Comment: I have it just like that, yet when I run my code with the environment set to production playground doesn't get initialized.